# What is the difference between Core_kernel.Heap and Core_kernel.FHeap?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

Jane Street's Core_kernel library has two heap implementations based on [pairing heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap):

> #### Module Core_kernel.Heap
>
> Heap implementation based on a pairing-heap.

([docs](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Heap/))

> #### Module Core_kernel.Fheap
>
> Functional heaps (implemented as pairing heaps).

([docs](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Fheap/))

From the descriptions, it's not clear to me what the difference is between them. When would I use one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference resides in the word "Functional" in your second quote: `Heap` is an imperative implementation, which can also be seen by the signature of e.g. the `add` function:

```
val add : 'a t ‑> 'a ‑> Core_kernel__.Import.unit
```

which returns `unit`, and modifies in place the existing heap.

On the other hand `FHeap` is functional, meaning that operations such as add will create new objects, leaving the original intact: in this case, the signature for add is

```
val add : 'a t ‑> 'a ‑> 'a t
```